# How to compute the symmetric difference of two lists using list comprehension?

Tags: haskell

To get the symmetric difference of two lists I think it would be a good idea to use list comprehension. But I don't know what I could do to remove the common elements of the lists and get the elements that are different.

For example

```
symDiff [1,2,3,4] [1,3,5]  -- should return [2,4,5].
```

So far I have

```
symDiff :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
symDiff xs ys =
```

Comment: What did you try? Hint: make use of `filter`.

Comment: Voting to close due to no attempt. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: What's supposed to happen if there are duplicates in a list?

Comment: is `symmdif a b = (dif a b)`? probably not. is it `symmdif a b = (dif b a)`? also unlikely. is it  `symmdif a b = one ++ two where ....`, perhaps? and what is `one` and `two`, then?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps, however i was unable to do it without using `Eq a`

```
symDiff :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
symDiff setA setB = [c | c <- setA, not $ (elem c [x | x <- setB])]
                        ++ [c | c <- setB, not $ (elem c [x | x <- setA])]
```

for

```
symDiff [1,2,3,4] [1,3,5]
```

will return: `[2,4,5]`